# Adding error bars to only one series (when multiple are present) using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, errorbar

I have a data frame that contains two y series. I have a scatter plot for the data but I cannot figure out how to add error bars for only one y series.

This is a pared down version of the code for my scatter plot.

```
MAndPScatter <- ggplot(MeasuredAndPredicted, aes(x=MeasuredAndPredicted$VoltageDifference)) + 
geom_point(aes(y = MeasuredAndPredicted$DeflectionMeasured) + 
geom_point(aes(y = MeasuredAndPredicted$DeflectionPredicted)) +
geom_abline(data=CRT2, intercept = -0.0006814, 
          slope = 0.0015342, lty=3) +
geom_abline(data=CRT2, intercept = -1.156e-18, 
          slope = 1.120e-03, lty=3)
```

And this is the plot

[image]

I only want to add error bars to the blue series but I don't know how to do that. I tried putting the normal error bar code (for the plot when it only had the blue series)

```
geom_errorbar(data=MeasuredAndPredicted, aes(ymin=MeasuredAndPredicted$DeflectionMeasured-Errors,
ymax=MeasuredAndPredicted$DeflectionMeasured+Errors))
```

which did not work and gave me this error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): ymin, ymax, x
```

For reference

```
dput(MeasuredAndPredicted) structure(list(VoltageDifference = c(1.1575, 3.5725, 
4.26, 5.56, 5.8225, 7.06, 9.865, 10.5475, 12.37), DeflectionMeasured = c(0.00125, 
0.0045, 0.00575, 0.00775, 0.00875, 0.01, 0.01425, 0.01575, 0.01825 ), 
DeflectionPredicted = c(0.0012964, 0.0040012, 0.0047712, 0.0062272, 0.0065212, 
0.0079072, 0.0110488, 0.0118132, 0.0138544)), .Names = c("VoltageDifference", 
"DeflectionMeasured", "DeflectionPredicted"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, e.g. paste the output of `dput(MeasuredAndPredicted)' or a subset of `MeasuredAndPredicted` to allow us to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: `dput(MeasuredAndPredicted)`                                                                     `structure(list(VoltageDifference = c(1.1575, 3.5725, 4.26, 5.56, 
5.8225, 7.06, 9.865, 10.5475, 12.37), DeflectionMeasured = c(0.00125, 
0.0045, 0.00575, 0.00775, 0.00875, 0.01, 0.01425, 0.01575, 0.01825
), DeflectionPredicted = c(0.0012964, 0.0040012, 0.0047712, 0.0062272, 
0.0065212, 0.0079072, 0.0110488, 0.0118132, 0.0138544)), .Names = c("VoltageDifference", 
"DeflectionMeasured", "DeflectionPredicted"), row.names = c(NA, 
9L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: How are you calculating errors?  Can you provide `dput(CRT2)` as we need see where the `Errors` variable is coming from.  Btw, paste the `dput` output into your question and not in the comments section.

Comment: `CRT2` is the exact same data frame as `MeasuredAndPredicted`. I was working between two scripts and they had different names for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can rewrite the errors you don't want as NA's and then they simply won't show up. Use the long format preferably.

```
df<-data.frame(x<-c(runif(10,0,50),runif(10,0,50)-2),type<-rep(c("measured","predicted"),each=10),y<-rnorm(20,5,10),errors<-c(runif(10,0,1),rep(NA,10)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y,group=type,colour=type)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", fill=NA)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-errors, ymax=y+errors), width=.5)
```

[image]